# Use Default UWP Pivot Styling (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp, styles

The TabbedPage control in Xamarin Forms renders as a FormsPivot instead of a standard UWP Pivot. It looks awful. It hurts my eyes. It's an abomination. I thought I'd grab the standard style here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299144.aspx

So, in the UWP side, I created a custom renderer which actually does make the control look better:

```
public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.Style = (wux.Style)wux.Application.Current.Resources["DefaultPivotStyle"];
    }
}
```

But, it renders like this:
[image]

I.e. doesn't show the content of the NavigationPage - it just shows the ToString() of the NavigationPage object. What's the easiest way to style this control with the native UWP look and feel?

Answer (score 4):

I have saw your screenshot, the problem is the native control of `TabbedPage` is  [`uwp:FormsPivot`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/8c5fd096945301a2db0d85baf77ce46812a8d89f/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.Phone/FormsPivot.cs), rather than `Pivot`. And `FormsPivot` is inherited from `Pivot` under `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP` namespace.

The `FormsPivot` has its own [`TabbedPageStyle`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/8c5fd096945301a2db0d85baf77ce46812a8d89f/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/TabbedPageStyle.xaml). So you could not use `Pivot` style directly. For your requirement, you could rewrite `Pivot` style like following.

```
<Style TargetType="Pivot" x:Key="DefaultPivotStyle">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" FontSize="50"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"
                        ContentTemplate="{ThemeResource ContainedPageTemplate}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Usage**

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    if (Control != null)
    {
        Control.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["DefaultPivotStyle"];      
    }
}
```

And you could also modify the whole shape by editing [`uwp:FormsPivot`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/8c5fd096945301a2db0d85baf77ce46812a8d89f/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.Phone/FormsPivot.cs) ControlTemplate.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="uwp:FormsPivot" x:Key="FormsPivotTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="RootElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="NavigationButtonsVisibility">
                        <VisualState x:Name="NavigationButtonsHidden" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="NavigationButtonsVisible">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="NextButton">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled" Storyboard.TargetName="NextButton">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousButton">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousButton">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="HeaderStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="HeaderDynamic" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="HeaderStatic">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="Header">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="StaticHeader">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Border x:Name="TopCommandBarArea" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{TemplateBinding ToolbarBackground}">
            <uwp:FormsCommandBar x:Name="CommandBar" Background="{TemplateBinding ToolbarBackground}" MinHeight="{ThemeResource TitleBarHeight}">
                <uwp:FormsCommandBar.Content>
                    <Border x:Name="TitleArea" Visibility="{TemplateBinding TitleVisibility}" Height="{ThemeResource TitleBarHeight}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="{TemplateBinding ToolbarForeground}" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
                    </Border>
                </uwp:FormsCommandBar.Content>
            </uwp:FormsCommandBar>
        </Border>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.Resources>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="NextTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                            <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E3;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="PreviousTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                            <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E2;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Grid.Resources>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False" HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid x:Name="PivotLayoutElement">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform x:Name="PivotLayoutElementTranslateTransform" />
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="LeftHeaderPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding LeftHeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding LeftHeader}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <ContentControl x:Name="HeaderClipper" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" UseSystemFocusVisuals="True">
                            <ContentControl.Clip>
                                <RectangleGeometry x:Name="HeaderClipperGeometry" />
                            </ContentControl.Clip>
                            <Grid Name="TabbedPageHeaderGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding ToolbarBackground}">
                                <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="StaticHeader" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header">
                                    <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform" />
                                            <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderOffsetTranslateTransform" />
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                </PivotHeaderPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </ContentControl>
                        <Button x:Name="PreviousButton" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" IsTabStop="False" IsEnabled="False" Margin="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonMargin}" Opacity="0" Template="{StaticResource PreviousTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" />
                        <Button x:Name="NextButton" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="36" IsTabStop="False" IsEnabled="False" Margin="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonMargin}" Opacity="0" Template="{StaticResource NextTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="RightHeaderPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding RightHeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding RightHeader}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1">
                            <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterCompositeTransform" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                        </ItemsPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </PivotPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
        <Border x:Name="BottomCommandBarArea" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Usage**

```
Control.Template = (ControlTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["FormsPivotTemplate"];
```

Comment: I see what you mean. I grabbed the XF style from the Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP project and compared it to the standard UWP style. They are two different to merge. I can't understand why the XF team decided to bifurcate the style so much. I'll be at it for days to get this to match the standard UWP style.

Comment: This worked great for me, managed to change the template as you suggested

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom style based on the default one like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyTabbedPageStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabbedPageStyle}">
   ...
</Style>
```

And modify only the properties and values you actually want to change. This will ensure the style still uses the FormsPresenter for the content and you can otherwise style the main template of the control itself.

The [`Xamarin.Forms` style](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/8c5fd096945301a2db0d85baf77ce46812a8d89f/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/TabbedPageStyle.xaml) also sets the `HeaderTemplate` and `ItemTemplate` which allow the content to render properly. If you want to set your custom style, you will have to define these two yourself or use their implementation.

```
<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Name="TabbedPageHeaderTextBlock" Text="{Binding Title}" 
                       Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>

<Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <uwp:FormsPresenter Content="{Binding}" 
                                ContentTemplate="{ThemeResource ContainedPageTemplate}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.

Comment: Sorry, where is uwp:FormsPresenter defined? My XAML editor doesn't like it.

Comment: I tried xmlns:uwp="using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's here https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/FormsPresenter.cs but the XAML editor won't accept it.

Comment: Oh, the problem is that the class is internal only... However, you can manually make your own copy of this class inside your project and use that copy. Alternatively, maybe even a simple `ContentPresenter` could work.

Comment: Hmmmm.... Thanks. Using a ContentPresenter works. But, I don't know what side effects it has. The code in the FormsPresenter does some stuff that doesn't compile in a custom class. So, I can't really say if this approach works or not. It seems to.

Comment: It seems the code in FormsPresenter is mostly doing visual modifications, so it should hopefully not affect many things...

Comment: Only concern could be the calls to  `page.SendAppearing()` and `page.SendDisappearing()`, because those apparently inform the page that it is displayed. But most of all it probably depends on what you actually want to display within the `FormsPivot`

Comment: What you could do however is to create a custom `Style` for the `FormsPivot` with `BasedOn="{StaticResource TabbedPageStyle}"`. This will ensure the style still uses the `FormsPresenter` for the content and you can otherwise style the main template of the control itself.

Comment: At the end of the day, this workaround doesn't work. The content inside the tabs isn't right. For example, I have a grid with two rows in my XF Xaml inside the tab, but the bottom row doesn't show when I put the style on. Why have the XF team decided to deviate from the standard look and feel so hard?

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware this question is a bit old, however, I've come across this problem as well and found a way to solve this. It requires some amount of overriding but if you really need this (as I do) then there'a a way. My solution is based on the existing answers here, however, I put them together into working thing as they didn't work for me separately. Here we go.

1) Take the content of [TabbedPageStyle](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/TabbedPageStyle.xaml) from Xamarin.Forms repo and put it into your App.xaml file. I know there's a problem with FormsPresenter here as this is an internal class. We'll fix it in a minute.

2) Create a new class in your UWP project (e.g. FormsPresenter). Take the content of [FormsPresenter](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/FormsPresenter.cs) file and paste it into your new class. Take a note on the namespace here. You'll need it in your App.xaml file. Example: Project.MyNamespace (in the class); xmlns:local="using:Project.MyNamespace" (in the App.xaml). Now you're able to use your local FormsPresenter instead of the original one:

```
<Style x:Key="TabbedPageStyle" TargetType="uwp:FormsPivot">
...
<Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- Change from "uwp" to "local" -->
                        <local:FormsPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{ThemeResource ContainedPageTemplate}" />
```

That's it! You have a working TabbedPageStyle which you can modify locally to get the style you want.

3) (Bonus) In my case, I had to style PivotHeaderItem which requires a bit more effort. Here's how I did it. Look for "PivotHeaderItem" in App.xaml - there's only one occurrence:

```
<Style x:Key="TabbedPageStyle" TargetType="uwp:FormsPivot">
...
<Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="48" />
</Style>
```

Swap this style with the one from [MS site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299142.aspx) or your local generic.xaml file. Now you can style the PivotHeaderItem the way you prefer.